# Why does an 'input submit' button prevent jQuery from submitting a form?

Tags: jquery

I had an 'input submit type' button on my form.

That button was submitting the form.

But when I added jQuery to do a dynamic submit it didn't work until I replaced the input submit button with a button element

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

to:

```
<button ....
```

What's the reason for that?

The dynamic form submit works fine now with the `button` element but it took me a while to figure out the cause.

Answer (score 2):

To do a dynamic submit with javascript you need to stop the default action of the Submit button from happening.

```
$(function () {
    $(':submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // submit the form dynamically
    });
});
```

Comment: @phil - My apologies.  That was a little underhanded of me.  I've switched my answer back to its original form.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to catch click events on specific form elements, the most robust way to intercept form submission is using the form's `submit` event, eg

```
$("#form-id").submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var action = form.attr('action');
    var method = form.attr('method');
    var data = form.serialize();

    /// you now have all the information required to
    /// perform a dynamic or AJAX form submission

    return false; // prevent default action
});
```

This method will not only catch click events on `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">` and `<button type="submit">` elements but will also work when the `Enter` key is pressed whilst focus is given to a text field.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `onSubmit="return false;"` in the form tag.

I can't give you a better answer than that without seeing your code.